# Endianess using %d specifier for float

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
  float a=2;
  printf("%d",a);
}
```

In my machine, float is 4 bytes, int is 2 bytes and bytes are stored in little-endian format.

a is 0x 00 00 00 02

Now as my machine is little endian, the bytes should be stored as 0x 02 00 00 00

Now when I use %d specifer, first 2 bytes should be fetched and output should be 512, but I am not getting that output.

Can someone tell me why is it happening?

Comment: Undefined behaviour? Why are you trying to print a float using the integer indicator? And how are you sure that `int` is 2 bytes?

Comment: Why is it undefined ? I should get first 2 bytes because I am using %d specifier right?

Comment: No - it's UB - you investigate and tell us why it is happening on your machine, with your compiler, your environment etc.

Comment: What use cases are there for using `"%d"` with a `float`?

Comment: Undefined behaviour because you're using something in a way it wasn't designed to be, and are getting strange results because of it.

Comment: Also, your umm.. forgot to tell us what output you did get when you tried it.

Comment: @SagarP When you use "%d" with printf, you promise printf that you will pass an integer. But you did not, you lied, and passed a float instead. This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: If you're working on an x86-64 system, the first few arguments to `printf` are passed via *registers*, not the stack, and different registers are used for floating point data vs. integer data.  So `printf` is effectively looking in the wrong place.  You can't rely on UB to produce *any* particular result.

Comment: @lurker, I completely forgot that floats are stored as single point precision. Thanks for pointing that out. Now I used char pointer and when I tried *(p+3), I got 64 as output (as expected).

Comment: Also don't forget `float` is promoted to a `double` in variadic parameter lists. So even if the hack works it won't do what is expected. If that sentence makes sense...

Comment: Voted to close as "unclear what you're asking" as this is clearly a XY problem. OP doesn't wand to "know what's happening" with his specific code, he wants to know how to access his `float` byte-wise or int-wise (which is a different question, really). He should have been asking that, instead of having us gaze into the crystal ball of figuring out UB.

Comment: @DevSolar: It is not clearly an XY problem. OP asks “Can someone tell me why is it happening?” It is perfectly feasible that they started by attempting to examine the bytes in a float, encountered behavior they did not understand, and are now inquiring about that in a desire to understand the internal workings of computers and compilers. You might suspect it is an XY problem, but it is certainly not clear. You can ask the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Using the wrong format specifier to `printf` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In this particular case, what it probably happening is that floating point types are not pushed onto the stack the same way integer types are.  You can't however depend on this behavior as the standard does not dictate what will happen.

If you want to print the bytes in a `float`, point an `unsigned char` to it and loop through the bytes:

```
float a=2;
unsigned char *c = (unsigned char *)&a;
int i;
for (i=0; i<sizeof(float); i++) {
    printf("%02x ", c[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Also, assuming your machine uses [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) format for floating point numbers, the representation for 2 isn't `0x00000002`, but `0x40000000`.

Comment: Yeah, I completely forgot that floats are represented using IEEE 754. Thanks.

Comment: In my machine it would be stored as 0x00 00 00 40 right ? When I tried *(p+3) with p as char pointer, it printed 64 as expected. But when I tried it with int as *(p+1) with p as int pointer, it is printing 16384. Can you tell me why is it happening? I think that with int too, output should be 64.

Comment: @SagarP: When you're using an `int` pointer, `p + 3` means "three times `sizeof int` from where `p` is pointing". How do you figure that should also print 64?

Comment: I wrote that I am using *(p+1) with int and not *(p+3) @DevSolar

Comment: @SagarP: Yea, you edited your comment a couple of times... this is neither here or there. You didn't really ask what you wanted to know, now did you?

Comment: @DevSolar, Can you please tell me why is not printing 64?

Comment: @SagarP: The only conversion specified by the standard is from `type` to a sequence of `unsigned char` and back *to the same type*. You're looking at undefined behaviour.... *again*. Why not ask what you are *actually* trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assuming that, in `printf("%d", a)`, the `float` value of `a` will be put in the same place that an `int` value would be put when passing an `int` parameter, and the `printf` will therefore read the bytes of the `float` as if they were an `int`.

This is not what happens in many C implementations. The C standard does not say that all parameters are passed in the same place or the same way regardless of their type. It does not define what the behavior is when you pass mismatched parameters to `printf`. In many C implementations, the first few floating-point arguments are passed in floating-point registers of the processor, which are separate from the general integer registers.

If you want to examine the bytes of an object, supported ways to do that include:

- Convert a pointer to the object to a pointer to `unsigned char` and then examine the bytes via the pointer to `unsigned char`.
- Use `memcpy` to copy the bytes to another object, such as `int x; memcpy(&x, &a, sizeof a);`. (The destination object should be the same size as the source object, so this is implementation-dependent.)
- Declare a union containing two types of object, the type you want to examine and another type such as `int` or an array of `unsigned char`. Write the value into one member of the union and read it from the other. E.g., `union { float f; int i; } x; x.f = a; printf("%d", x.i);`. Again, the sizes of the two objects should match.

Comment: In my machine the number would be stored as 0x00 00 00 40 right ? When I tried *(p+3) with p as char pointer, it printed 64 as expected. But when I tried it with int as *(p+1) with p as int pointer, it is printing 16384. Can you tell me why is it happening? I think that with int too, output should be 64

Comment: @SagarP `*(p+1)` is the next `int`, not the next `unsigned char`.

Comment: @SagarP: With a little endian machine, the bytes 00 00 00 40 as one four-byte integer would be 40000000. As two two-byte integers, they would be 0000 and 4000. 4000 (hex) is 16384.